# Combining a property value in a parent document and an ElemMatch in an array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have these classes:

```
public class Parent
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ChildInfo ChildInfo { get; set; }
}

public class ChildInfo
{
    public int Age { get; set; }

    ...other properties...
}
```

So given a collection of Parents, I need to return a Parent with a specific Id, but only if it does not have a Child with a ChildInfo that has a specific age.

I think I am close. Here is what I have so far:

```
var childQuery = Query<Child>.NE(c => c.ChildInfo.Age, 5);

var finalresult = collection.Find(Query.And(Query<Parent>.EQ(p => p.Id, 3245),
                                            Query<Parent>.ElemMatch( p => p.Children, builder => childQuery)));
```

However, I get these results:

When there is no Parent 3245, the query returns nothing (correct).

When Parent 3245 has no children, the query returns nothing (wrong).

When Parent 3245 has one child age 3 the query returns the Parent (correct).

When Parent 3245 has one child age 3 and one child age 5 the query returns the Parent (wrong).

When Parent 3245 has one child age 3 and one child age 7 the query returns the Parent (correct).

It appears as if the first part of the query (Parent.Id) works. But the second half seems to return the Parent all the time except when the list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the first problem, it seems that you'll have to use a `Query.Or` to surround the `Query.ElemMatch` and an additional `Query.Exists` to test for case when there are no child elements.

Regarding the second problem, it seems that Mongo kind of unwinds the children array and if it finds a document that matches your query, it marks the query as true. So in the case of ages 3 and 5, the fact that it finds 3, which is Not Equal to 5, it satisfies the query and you get a wrong result.
I think, but I'm not 100% sure it's the best way, it'd be better to use `Query.Not(Query<Child>.EQ(c => c.ChildInfo.Age, 5))`.